# Populate router without dispatch

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

How can i populate the router with all the available routes (controller/action) in my application without dispatching the request to the front controller?

My entry script is like:

```
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->bootstrap();

MY OWN CODE THAT PROCESSES THE REQUEST
```

Comment: for the love of zend why?

Comment: because this is the entry point for a callback and i don't want to load all zend framework.

Comment: can you change the entry point to something else? or use a different framework like `slim` for example

Comment: Provided you are adding routes in the standard way during Bootstrap - say in a method called `_initRoutes()` during which you load a bunch of routes, either in code or from a `.ini` file or from a PHP array -  what you have above should do it.